# Longtable table and vertical spacing problem

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I am trying to design a title page macro with several equally spaced parts.  One of those part contains a longtable table.  When I include the table, some of the \vfill commands no longer seem to expand to equalize the spacing.  I'm hoping someone here can see something I'm not seeing here.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

% A bit less than half the page width
\newlength{\halfwd}
\setlength{\halfwd}{((\textwidth) * \real{0.95} - \columnsep)/2}%

% A longtable that I want as one of the page components
\def\lt{%
  \setlength\extrarowheight{12pt}%
  \begin{longtable}{p{\halfwd}p{\halfwd}}%
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{%
    11111111111111111111\\
    11111111111111111111\\
    11111111111111111111}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{22222222222222222222\\
    22222222222222222222\\
    22222222222222222222}\\

    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{33333333333333333333\\
    33333333333333333333\\
    33333333333333333333}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{44444444444444444444\\
    44444444444444444444\\
    44444444444444444444}\\

    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{55555555555555555555\\
    55555555555555555555\\
    55555555555555555555}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{66666666666666666666\\
    66666666666666666666\\
    66666666666666666666}\\
  \end{longtable}
}

% I expect each part of the page to be equally spaced and all the parts together
% to fill up the whole page.
  \begin{center}
    \hrule
    Part I
    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part II
    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part III
    {\texttt \lt}
    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part IV
    \vfill
    \hrule
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is what the output looks like.  Parts I and II get squished to minimal size, while it seems all Parts ought to be of equally spaced-out.

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNAd4.png)

Comment: A *long*table in a context which is only on one page is nonsense. Why don't you use a simple tabular?

Comment: Beside this you naturally need some \par (empty lines) if you want to use \vfill this way. And use \ttfamily instead of \texttt.

Comment: why do you have `\parboxes` nested inside parboxes and also there is no need to guess .95 scalefactor (you are relying on .95\textwidth+4\tabcolsep being `\textwidth` which is not usually true)

Comment: The partial page above a longtable is boxed (thus forcing glue to its natural length, 0 on the case of `\vfil` in order to allow longtable to know how big its first page needs to be, it would require quite a lot of code to do anything else, but you don't need longtable if it is just two parboxes per line. All entries are fixed width so will align anyway there is no need for a table.

Comment: David, you're right.  I didn't see that the longtable attributes duplicate the parboxes in the body.  Thanks.  The width is just to leave some margin on both sides, not assuming any relationship to \tabcolsep.

Comment: This example is just an example, in actual use, I won't know how many there will be.  Also, I want to be able to use the same longtable construct in other parts of the document where stretching over multiple pages might make sense.  I admit it doesn't make much sense for a titlepage.

Your first sentence sounds like the key.  But how is it that the pre-table text is boxed?

Comment: @DanielDoherty you _are_ assuming a relation in that you are assuming (or know in this case) that .95\textwidth+4\tabcolsep is less than \textwidth

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "how is it that the pre-table text is boxed" longtable has to switch output routines (a somewhat scary and delicate operation mid-document)  the partial page so far is saved boxed and re-inserted after the switch. Doing anything else is likely to require major changes to longtable

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I think I get get what you were saying about the text above the longtable being boxed.  That is done in the longtable code so it will know how much page is left to format the first page of the longtable, if I understand correctly.  In which case, it would seem there really is nothing that I can do to keep that from happening, right?

Comment: Our comments are crossing.  You answered my question, David.  Much appreciated.

Comment: actually it's not so bad, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid longtable boxing the content of the page-so-far and so freezing the vertical skips at their natural width of 0pt by removing a `\vbox` as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht
%      \vbox
        {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
  \else
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
  \fi}

\begin{document}

% A bit less than half the page width
\newlength{\halfwd}
\setlength{\halfwd}{((\textwidth) * \real{0.95} - \columnsep)/2}%

% A longtable that I want as one of the page components
\def\lt{%
  \setlength\extrarowheight{12pt}%
  \begin{longtable}{p{\halfwd}p{\halfwd}}%
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{%
    11111111111111111111\\
    11111111111111111111\\
    11111111111111111111}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{22222222222222222222\\
    22222222222222222222\\
    22222222222222222222}\\

    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{33333333333333333333\\
    33333333333333333333\\
    33333333333333333333}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{44444444444444444444\\
    44444444444444444444\\
    44444444444444444444}\\

    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{55555555555555555555\\
    55555555555555555555\\
    55555555555555555555}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{66666666666666666666\\
    66666666666666666666\\
    66666666666666666666}\\
  \end{longtable}
}

% I expect each part of the page to be equally spaced and all the parts together
% to fill up the whole page.
  \begin{center}
    \hrule
    Part I
    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part II
    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part III
    {\texttt \lt}
    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part IV
    \vfill
    \hrule
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoa.  Nice!  That actually solves it.  Thanks David!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what layout you really have in mind. But with a few empty lines, tabular instead of longtable and \ttfamily one gets something that looks more or less sensible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

% A bit less than half the page width
\newlength{\halfwd}
\setlength{\halfwd}{((\textwidth) * \real{0.95} - \columnsep)/2}%

% A longtable that I want as one of the page components
\def\lt{%
  \setlength\extrarowheight{12pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}%
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{%
    11111111111111111111\\
    11111111111111111111\\
    11111111111111111111}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{22222222222222222222\\
    22222222222222222222\\
    22222222222222222222}\\

    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{33333333333333333333\\
    33333333333333333333\\
    33333333333333333333}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{44444444444444444444\\
    44444444444444444444\\
    44444444444444444444}\\

    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{55555555555555555555\\
    55555555555555555555\\
    55555555555555555555}&
    \parbox[t]{\halfwd}{66666666666666666666\\
    66666666666666666666\\
    66666666666666666666}\\
  \end{tabular}}

% I expect each part of the page to be equally spaced and all the parts together
% to fill up the whole page.
  \begin{center}
    \hrule
    \vfill 

    Part I

    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part II

    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part III

    {\ttfamily \lt}

    \vfill
    \hrule
    \vfill
    Part IV

    \vfill
    \hrule
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike, thanks for the suggestions.  The longtable construct here may appear other places besides the title page and may, though it usually does not, take more than one page.  

Since I don't know in advance how many \parbox elements will need to be displayed, I use longtable so that it can handle either case.  Using tabular will not work when the number of \parbox elements is large.

Do you see any way to get the effect you show while still using the longtable environment?

Comment: As you are using fix width boxes as cells anyway I don't really see why you use a tabular at all.

Comment: Ulrike, in actual practice, they are not fixed width.  They are name and address blocks for use in a legal brief.

Comment: Ulrike, I am accepting your answer.  With your answer and @DavidCarlise's comments above, I believe I understand what's going on now.  Thanks.