# tabularx affects vertical spacing on titlepage

Tags: titles, tabularx

I noticed that the `tabularx` environment affects my titlepage's layout. My titlepage looks as intended when using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{5cm}{\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\bfseries Title\par}
    \vspace*{5mm}{\fontsize{17}{17}\selectfont\bfseries Subtitle\par\vspace{5mm}}
    Foo
    \hrule height0pt depth0pt width1pc
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \end{tabular}
    %\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l}
    %\end{tabularx}
    Bar
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

but when I use the `tabularx` environment instead of the `tabular`, the vertical filling space is not inserted and the text "Bar" is put directly below "Foo".

Good:
[image]
Bad:
[image]

Before starting to play with minipages, I ask myself what happened here and if there might be a simple way to change this behaviour.

Comment: [This question with a similar issue with `longtable`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391156/82917) is related. `ltablex` redefines `tabularx` in order to make it similar to `longtable`. A very bad idea, in my opinion. (I mean redefining `tabularx` instead of providing a _new_ environment with a _different_ name.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\vfill` and nest `tabularx` in a minipage:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{5cm}{\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\bfseries Title\par}
    \vspace*{5mm}{\fontsize{17}{17}\selectfont\bfseries Subtitle\par\vspace{5mm}}
    Foo
    \hrule height0pt depth0pt width1pc
\vfill
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
    Bar
    \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]